# Get Package name in react-native

Tags: android, react-native

I am new in react-native development. How we can get **package** name in `react-native`. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can use the package [device info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info) https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info

and use it like this , its a pretty well maintained library

```
  DeviceInfo.getInstallerPackageName().then((installerPackageName) => {
      // Play Store: "com.android.vending"
      // Amazon: "com.amazon.venezia"
      // Samsung App Store: "com.sec.android.app.samsungapps"
      // iOS: "AppStore", "TestFlight", "Other"
    });
```

Or you can check this library for package name [rn-check](https://github.com/kimxogus/react-native-version-check)

```
console.log(VersionCheck.getPackageName());        // com.reactnative.app
console.log(VersionCheck.getCurrentBuildNumber()); // 10
console.log(VersionCheck.getCurrentVersion());     // 0.1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would without using third party package would be:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
const bundleId = NativeModules.RNDeviceInfo?.bundleId;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with simple lib [Version Check](https://github.com/kimxogus/react-native-version-check)

Just run `VersionCheck.getPackageName()`